# [iPhone]How to set padding of grouped tableview section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Hi I have a grouped tableview and i need to change the padding of sections.I need to have between 2 sections 10px.
 I have tried to dissmiss header like that:

```
    CGRect frame = [myTableView rectForFooterInSection:indexPath.section];
    frame.size.height = 0;

    CGRect frame1 = [myTableView rectForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    frame1.size.height = 0;
```

But it does not work.
Can i change the padding.If you want some example i find:Add event in calendar on iPhone

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those frames are not pointers, when you change them the original rect isn't affected.  They are stored separately in memory.

It seems like the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` UITableView delegate is what you are after.  You can find more info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html